# DHCPD ip6, No subnet6 declaration for enp2s0 (2001:470:1f1a:5b3::2)

Tags: debian, dhcp, ipv6, interface

This is weird! I got IP4 DHCP, it works. But with IPV6 not working.

Do you know what it could be?

**INTERFACE**

```
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
    metric 10
    address 192.168.78.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.78.255       
    gateway    192.168.78.1

iface enp2s0 inet6 static
    metric 10
    address 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::2
    netmask 64
    gateway 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::1

auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
    address 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::2
    netmask 64
    endpoint 216.66.87.14
    local 192.168.78.20
    ttl 255
    gateway 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::1

allow-hotplug enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
    metric 30
    post-up ip route add 192.168.81.0/24 dev enp1s0 src 192.168.81.20 table rt2
    post-up ip route add default via 192.168.81.1 dev enp1s0 table rt2
    post-up    ip rule add from 192.168.81.20/32 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add to 192.168.81.20/32 table rt2
```

**DHCPD6**

```
subnet6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::/64 {
    range6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::50 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::ffff;
    range6 2001:470:1f1b:5b3::/64 temporary;
    option dhcp6.name-servers 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::2;
    option dhcp6.domain-search "patrikx3.tk";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
root@server:~# dhcpd -6 -d -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf enp2s0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf
Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd6.leases
PID file: /var/run/dhcpd6.pid
Wrote 0 NA, 0 TA, 0 PD leases to lease file.

No subnet6 declaration for enp2s0 (2001:470:1f1a:5b3::2).
** Ignoring requests on enp2s0.  If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet6 declaration
   in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface enp2s0 is attached. **


Not configured to listen on any interfaces!

If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
process and the information we find helpful for debugging..

exiting.
```

Comment: Your config seems wrong. The IPv6 addresses of the tunnel and of the LAN can't be the same. You should have different address for every network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the solution:

```
subnet6 2001:470:1f1a:5b3::20/128
```

I had to look in my ifconifg

```
Destination                    Next Hop               Flag Met  Ref Use If
2001:470:1f1a:5b3::1/128       ::                     U    1024 1     4 he-ipv6
2001:470:1f1a:5b3::/64         ::                     Un   256  2    24 he-ipv6
2001:470:1f1a:5b3::/64         ::                     U    256  1     1 enp2s0
fe80::/64                      ::                     U    256  0     0 enp1s0
fe80::/64                      ::                     Un   256  0     0 he-ipv6
fe80::/64                      ::                     U    256  2    72 enp2s0
::/0                           2001:470:1f1a:5b3::1   UG   10   2    11 enp2s0
::/0                           2001:470:1f1a:5b3::1   UG   1024 5    68 he-ipv6
::/0                           ::                     !n   -1  1109832 lo
::1/128                        ::                     Un   0    3  8351 lo
2001:470:1f1a:5b3::2/128       ::                     Un   0    2   267 lo
2001:470:1f1a:5b3::20/128      ::                     Un   0    2    44 lo
fe80::c0a8:4e14/128            ::                     Un   0    1     0 lo
fe80::9ade:d0ff:fe04:23c3/128  ::                     Un   0    1     0 lo
fe80::eeaa:a0ff:fe1b:4d84/128  ::                     Un   0    2    73 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                     U    256  1     5 enp1s0
ff00::/8                       ::                     U    256  0     0 he-ipv6
ff00::/8                       ::                     U    256  1   237 enp2s0
::/0                           ::                     !n   -1  1109832 lo
```